# Unable to locate input text element

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to find input text element in selenium facebook webdriver.

I want it to run further even if it is not able to find the text input. I am using the following code but not working :

```
if(count($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('custname'))) > 0){
    $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('custname'))->sendKeys("John Doe");

}
```

Actually the problem is if there is data in server it won't show an input text, it just shows a span tag. but if there is no data in server it shows input text. that's why i just want to check if input text exists then insert data in input else continue.

The error is :
Fatal error:  Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: If element does not exist hen fatal error arise you can handle through exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException;

try {
    $search = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('custname'));
} catch (NoSuchElementException $e) {
    echo "Not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is visible:

```
$userName = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('custname'));

if ($userName->isVisible()) {
    $userName->sendKeys("John Doe");
}
```

Comment: I don't want to wait, i just want to check if it exists then execute if not the continue.

Comment: You won't wait 20 seconds, script will continue as soon as element is located. The thing is your script is executing so fast it may be trying to send keys to an element which is not usable yet.

Comment: Sir, actually the problem is if there is data in server it won't show an input text, it just shows a span tag. but if there is no data in server it shows input text. that's why i just want to check if input text exists then insert data in input else continue.

Comment: You did not mention that earlier. I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry for that, but unfortunately, this answer didn't work either.  :(
I will update my question.